# Как сделать отличные друг от друга <form> если они генерируются по шаблону

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

как можно сделать так, что бы скрипт брал не самую первую попавшуюся форму, а брал первую или допустим последнюю или 4, фильтр ставить я не могу, вот начало скрипта(дальше нечего смотреть)

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
$("#add").on("click", function () {
    let currentProduct = {
        name: $("input[name=name]").val(),
        price: $("input[name=price]").val(),
        id: $("input[name=id]").val(),
        descption: $("input[name=about]").val(),
        count: 1,
        category: $("input[name=category]").val(),
        img: $("input[name=img]").val()
    };
```

Эта часть скрипта берёт данные с формы, но форм 8, а он берёт первую ибо фильтра нет, и не будет(нельзя его делать), теперь вопрос, уважаемые знатоки, есть ли способ как нибудь привязать форму к определённому скрипту и кнопке?
Дело в том, что формы генерируются по шаблону, на странице их 8, тоесть я не могу задать допустим определённую цифру каждой форме (если могу, напишите как пожалуйста) я уже не знаю что делать, провозился с этим 2 недели, если напишите ответ, пожалуйста можно поподробней, а то я походу чайник в этом деле...

на всякий случай форма

```
<form>
            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="img" value="<?php echo $row["img"]; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="about" value="<?php echo $row["about"]; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="category" value="<?php echo $row["category"]; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

если у вас `id` уникальное значение (а так и должно быть) для того чтобы отличить формы друг от друга можете добавить `data-атрибут` к кнопке и  сделать так:

```js
$(".add").on("click", function() {
  const id = $(this).data('form-id');
  const form = $('.form-' + id);
  let currentProduct = {
    name: form.find("input[name=name]").val(),
    price: form.find("input[name=price]").val(),
    id: form.find("input[name=id]").val(),
    descption: form.find("input[name=about]").val(),
    count: 1,
    category: form.find("input[name=category]").val(),
    img: form.find("input[name=img]").val()
  };
});
```

```html
<form class="form-<?php echo $row[" id "]; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $row[" name "]; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row[" price "]; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="img" value="<?php echo $row[" img "]; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="about" value="<?php echo $row[" about "]; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="category" value="<?php echo $row[" category "]; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row[" id "]; ?>">
  <button class="add" data-form-id="<?php echo $row[" id "]; ?>">Добавить в корзину</button> 
</form>
```

Или можно воспользоваться методом `closest` который ищет первого родителя по заданному селектору, если `button` находится внутри формы

```js
$(".add").on("click", function() {
  const form = $(this).closest('form');
  let currentProduct = {
    name: form.find("input[name=name]").val(),
    price: form.find("input[name=price]").val(),
    id: form.find("input[name=id]").val(),
    descption: form.find("input[name=about]").val(),
    count: 1,
    category: form.find("input[name=category]").val(),
    img: form.find("input[name=img]").val()
  };
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $row[" name "]; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row[" price "]; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="img" value="<?php echo $row[" img "]; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="about" value="<?php echo $row[" about "]; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="category" value="<?php echo $row[" category "]; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row[" id "]; ?>">
  <button class="add">Добавить в корзину</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: Всё очень хорошо, не подскажете как сделать кнопку для каждой формы? Этот скрипт должен добавлять товары в корзину, но он добавляет только первый товар при нажатии любой кнопки код которых(регулировать так же могу только шаблон для генерации) <button class="add">Добавить в корзину</button>

Comment: @Sergey1006 сделал изменения, которые должны сработать для вашего случая

Comment: То ли я чего то не понимаю, то ли что, но всё равно добавляется только первый товар

Comment: В скрипте поменял, на странице тоже поменял, но никак...